# Automatically maintaining test schema doesn't work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails, rails-migrations

For my Rails 4 app i have the following written in my `spec_helper.rb` to maintain the test database automatically:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema
```

But as it seems this doesn't work, because i still get the message afterwards, that there are migrations pending.

So, i debugged this and found the following line in active_records'  [`migration.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L587) which actually executes the schema preparation (or should):

```
system("bin/rake db:test:prepare")
```

But when i try to execute this line separatly in a rails console nothing happens. Calling it with

```
`bin/rake db:test:prepare`
```

to get the output gives me the following error

```
Errno::ENOEXEC: Exec format error - bin/rake db:test:prepare
```

So is this a bug in rails or did i just something wrong? I am on windows if that matters, but it didn't work on my co-workers mac too.